# How to get external JSON with PHP that has content-type text/plain?

Tags: php, json

I am trying to fetch an external JSON response with my PHP back-end
But my problem is that the external endpoint is returned as the Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8, and that only gives me gibberish when I read it.

```
string '����������ݒ�J�� ... etc...
```

Is there a way to encode that response?

This is what I have done:

```
$response = file_get_contents('external_url');
```

I have also tried this:

```
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents('external_url'), true);
```

Comment: Any errors on processing the result? If you only display the data, have you set the document to utf-8? `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');`

Comment: If I use the json_decode I get null and if I set the header above there is no difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't really matter to PHP what `Content-Type` the response declares, it doesn't *do* anything with that information. You're getting exactly the same response body whether the header says `text/plain` or JSON.

More likely the response is *compressed* and you need to uncompress it with [`gzinflate`](http://php.net/gzinflate) or such.

Comment: If I do that I only get an error... "gzinflate(): data error" These are the content types from the orginal response:
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Length:344662
Content-Type:text/plain;charset=utf-8

Comment: Ok, I can set you as the correct answer, since you really pointed me in the right direction, I had to use readgzfile. If you want you can edit that in to your answer :)

Comment: If you have to use `readgzfile` that means you're storing the content in a file... which is quite different usage than `gzinflate`...?! Anyway, the manual page of `gzinflate` I link to links to the other functions, and I explicitly left it up to you to figure out precisely which one is the appropriate one...